# How to loop through a json array in Flask by javascript?

Tags: javascript, python, arrays, json

There is a json array in my html passed from Flask. But when I try to use `javascript` to loop through it, it seems like I can only get the subscript of array. The results display as `0,1,2...` kind of thing. How can I get the value of json array instead of the subscript?

Json Array:

```
json_array = ["EPGD", "KEGG"]
```

Javascript code:

```
for (var item in json_array){
    alert(item);
}
```

Comment: Use `for-loop` instead of `for-in` loop

Comment: Got it! Thank you!!!!!